# Trying to make Install zulucrypt but cannot find packages

Tags: drivers, package-management, dependencies, tar, cmake

I have downloaded the source code of zulucrypt from http://code.google.com/p/zulucrypt/ because there is no .deb file. This is my first time to install from source and i need a little help by doing this.

While reading and following instructions from the Build_Instructions file, i have to install some packages first. Then make a build dir, so i did.

```
To build the backends as well as front ends, run the following command:
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MINSIZEREL . ..
```

I get this error message:

```
-- checking for module 'blkid'
--   package 'blkid' not found
-- checking for module 'pwquality'
--   package 'pwquality' not found
-- checking for module 'tcplay'
--   package 'tcplay' not found
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:47 (message):
  ERROR: could not find blkid package
```

When i type in the terminal tcplay it explains what options are available for usage, so i guess it is already installed on my system. And i remember doing that with the command: apt-get install tcplay

Why can cmake command not find the package? What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

this is mhogomchungu,maintainer of zuluCrypt.

thanks for trying to check it out.

to build,make sure you have the following packages already installed

cmake

pkg-config

libsecret-1-dev

libcryptsetup-dev

libblkid-dev

libpwquality-dev

libtcplay-dev

libdevmapper-dev

uuid-dev

libgcrypt11-dev

libqt4-dev

libudev-dev

chrpath

bzip2

i do not think ubuntu has tcplay library package and hence,you may miss libtcplay-dev and the only thing you will end up missing is the ability to create truecrypt volumes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried it again and now i get the following error message: 'CMake Error at zuluCrypt-gui/lxqt_wallet/backend/CMakeLists.txt:11 (MESSAGE): could not find gcrypt header file'

Comment: Thats probably because you did not install libgcrypt11-dev. I dont get notified here when you write your comment and hence i will respond faster if you ask me using my email address as specified in the project's main page.